# openjdk:8 and nonProxyHosts is not working

Tags: java, docker, proxy, ip

I had the following docker configuration:

```
FROM openjdk:8

ADD *.jar /service.jar

VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8080

# Set timezone CET (DE Time)
ENV TZ=CET
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

CMD echo "The Service will start..." && \
java -DsocksProxyHost=192.168.1.250 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="192.168.1.5|192.168.1.36" -jar /service.jar
```

The problem I have with this is the non proxy is totally ignored in java 8. If I switch into openjdk:9 is working fine, but I cannot do that because the service has stuff that is strongly depends on jdk 8.

I tried without quoting, escaping the pipe character but nothing :(

Somebody has this strange problem, and a solution/workaround for that?

Comment: That sounds like a change in the newer JVM, the way you're describing it; does the some configuration work with the same JVM version outside of Docker?

Comment: Pff, it is hard to reproduce outside of docker because it is on GCP, but yes at the and I'll do some magic to try on local.

Comment: the `socksProxyHost` should be `http.proxyHost`

Comment: nope, there is socksProxyHost because it is used for JDBC

Comment: so where to send the hosts with http.nonProxyHosts ?

Comment: Http is stays on socks, so the socks proxy is applied for each protocol over the tcp stack. The idea behind is to have proxy for the plain socket JDBC but to not have for the HTTP.

Comment: OK, on the other hand please unaccept the unswer so people did not think your question is already  answered

Answer (score 6):

Solved!

After studying the sources of openjdk8 and openjdk9  I figured out I need to specify twice the non proxy ip list. So the solution for openjdk8 is:

```
java -DsocksProxyHost=192.168.1.250 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="192.168.1.5|192.168.1.36" -DsocksNonProxyHosts="192.168.1.5|192.168.1.36" -jar /service.jar
```